# A question about compact sets: how to prove $g$ must be an isometry

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,p)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose that $g:X\rightarrow X$ is a function such that for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ we have $p(g(x_1),g(x_2))\geq p(x_1,x_2)$.  Prove that, in fact, $g$ must be an isometry ($p(g(x_1),g(x_2))=p(x_1,x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$) and that g is bijective.

I am stuck here, and I have tried many times, but still have no idea how to solve the question.
Can someone tell me how to solve this question?

Comment: is $f$  onto function?

Comment: see Theorem 1.4 https://people.math.osu.edu/memoli.2/courses/cse-topics-2014/background.pdf

Comment: @mesel You don't need to assume it to be onto.  Once you show that this is an isometry, it follows that $g$ must be onto (actually bijective, but injectivity is easy)..

Comment: we need to prove f is onto function

Comment: see the link in my previous comment, Theorem 1.3 shows the map is onto

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201072/let-m-d-be-a-compact-metric-space-and-fm-to-m-such-that-dfx-fy-g